# Saving file as an .xlxs file format

Tags: vba, excel

I've tried using this code to save the file as `.xlsx` but I got an issue that the saved file is having the file type`17 file` not `Microsoft .....`

```
fName = "Test 08.24.17"
wb.SaveAs FileName:=fName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

also tried

```
wb.SaveAs FileName:=fName, FileFormat:=51
```

[image: file type error]

Originally the file is in `.csv` file format. Can you help me figure this out?

Comment: What is value of fName variable?

Comment: @Sixthsense Question Updated :)

Comment: fName = "Test 08.24.17.xlsx"

Comment: @MatSnow I've also tried that, but never got the luck, the file is still `.csv` upon saving.

Comment: add extension.  fName = "Test 08.24.17.xlsx"

Comment: @Sixthsense File is still `.csv`. :S

Comment: Tested at my end and It's working fine for me.

Comment: @Sixthsense Does Excel version possibly affect this one? I'm currently using Excel 2016

Comment: Your file is of type "17 File" because you are using dots in your filename, so the last part ".17" is expected to be the file extension. Adding the ".xlsx" as mentioned by @Sixthsense should work, but make sure to correctly write ".xlsx" and not ".xlxs" and in your question.

Comment: I have Excel 2016 and code with correct extension is working fine, so it should not be version dependent.

Comment: @VincentG I've tried it again and it saves as `.xlsx` file, but if I open it again, it prompts that the file is corrupt or the file extension is not valid. Apologies for the above error, it's just a typo :)

Comment: There might be a problem elsewhere, because opening a .csv file, then saving it with the above mentioned code works fine here.

Comment: @VincentG Owww! :S, gotta trace all my codes :S

Answer (score 0):

wb.SaveAs Filename:= fName & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook